# Detecting socket type (Secure and Insecure) bluetooth android

Tags: android, bluetooth

Hot to detecting socket type bluetooth in android? for example;

I connect to a Bluetooth printer sometimes works with

device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord ( uuid ) ;

(Samsung , Motorola ) but for other devices such as Lenovo , Huawei , works with

device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord ( uuid ) ;

How to detect the type of socket if it is safe or unsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is a core android, condition is :

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");  
int sdk = Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK);  
if(sdk < 17){  
    //sdk 4.2.2?? java.io.IOException: Connection refused   
    socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);  
}else {  
    socket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);  
}
```

very good for me, bye!